# abp.io how to get 2 or more WithDetails in Repository?

Tags: c#, repository, abp

I have entity:

```
class Contract
{
   public TenantProfile TenantProfile { get; set; }
   public ContractStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

Service (`override GetAsync(Id)`):

```
 var contractWithDetails = (await Repository.WithDetailsAsync(x => x.Status)).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

But property `TenantProfile` - null, because I can't execute `WithDetailsAsync` for `IQueryable`. How to solve my problem and execute more then 2 `WithDetailsAsync`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is suggested to create an extension method for each **aggregate root** with **sub collections**:

```cs
public static IQueryable<Contract> IncludeDetails(
    this IQueryable<Contract> queryable,
    bool include = true)
{
    if (!include)
    {
        return queryable;
    }

    return queryable
        .Include(x => x.TenantProfile)
        .Include(x => x.ContractStatus);
}
```

Now you can override `WithDetailsAsync`:

```cs
public override async Task<IQueryable<Contract>> WithDetailsAsync()
{
    // Uses the extension method defined above
    return (await GetQueryableAsync()).IncludeDetails();
}
```

Now your `WithDetailsAsync` method includes both of them.

See more on [ABP Entity Framework Core Integration Best Practices docs](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Best-Practices/Entity-Framework-Core-Integration).